# DataStax Enterprise - COPY FROM csv file to CQL Table which has a User Defined Type column

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I'm using apache-cassandra 3.0 and am trying to import a csv data file (generated from Microsoft excel file) to a Table which has a User Defined Type column. I've created a UDT as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE keyspace.UDT_name (column_A int, column_B text);

CREATE TABLE keyspace.Table_name (UDT_name FROZEN<UDT_name>,column_C,
  column_D, PRIMARY KEY ((UDT_name), column_C));

COPY keyspace.Table_name (UDT_name, column_C, column_D) FROM 'data.csv';
```

Have tried using a csv file containing that contains `column_A, column_B, column_C, column_D`.  Get error message "list index out of range".

I added to the `COPY FROM` command,

```
WITH "UDT_name"=VALUES ("column_A <int>", "column_B <text>");
```

and Get error message "Improper COPY command".

The problem I have is getting csv data file containing `column_A int, column_B text, column_C, column_D` into `keyspace.Table_name` which has column UDT_name.  I have looked through DataStax manuals for guidance and tried numerous other trail and error attempts without success. The `INSERT INTO` command is not suitable for the size of data to import.

Appreciate any help with this problem.

Additional info: `column_A` has multiple rows with the same data and `column_B` has multiple rows with `NULL` values so both can't be used as primary keys.  However, in creating a UDT, the data creates unique data suitable as a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

UDTs should be supported for copy from/to CSV files.

I suggest creating in Cassandra your keyspace/UDT/table, manually insert a few records in the expected format, then copy to a CSV file to see what the format looks like.

Here's an example:

```
$ cqlsh
create type test.udt (a int, b text);
create table test.foo (udt frozen<udt>, c text, d text, primary key ((udt), c));
insert into test.foo (udt, c, d) values ({a: 1, b:'a'}, 'apple', 'audi');
insert into test.foo (udt, c, d) values ({a: 2, b:'b'}, 'banana', 'buick');
insert into test.foo (udt, c, d) values ({a: 3, b:'c'}, 'cherry', 'chevy');
copy foo (udt, c, d) to 'test.csv';

$ cat test.csv
"{a: 3, b: 'c'}",cherry,chevy
"{a: 1, b: 'a'}",apple,audi
"{a: 2, b: 'b'}",banana,buick
```

You can see that the UDT is represented as a single "field" in the CSV file, with the 'a' and 'b' values defined within. This may be the crux of your issue mapping from Excel into UDTs. You could write a script to transform the CSV file into the format Cassandra needs, or you could adjust your data model to include all columns rather than UDTs.

There also may be some concerns about using a UDT as primary key; see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26511395) for one discussion.

**Update 2016-01-26**

To the question about how a null values handled, here's a further example where we add a couple more rows with null values, then look at the CSV file to see how they're represented:

```
$ cqlsh
insert into test.foo (udt, c) values ({a: 4}, 'delta');
insert into test.foo (udt, c) values ({b:'e'}, 'echo');
cqlsh> select * from test.foo;
 udt               | c      | d
-------------------+--------+-------
 {a: null, b: 'e'} |   echo |  null
    {a: 3, b: 'c'} | cherry | chevy
    {a: 1, b: 'a'} |  apple |  audi
    {a: 2, b: 'b'} | banana | buick
   {a: 4, b: null} |  delta |  null
copy test.foo (udt, c, d) to 'test.csv';

$ cat test.csv
"{a: , b: 'e'}",echo,
"{a: 3, b: 'c'}",cherry,chevy
"{a: 1, b: 'a'}",apple,audi
"{a: 2, b: 'b'}",banana,buick
"{a: 4, b: }",delta,
```

Notice the null values are simply empty in the CSV file. They aren't shown as null or 'null', just empty.

Comment: Have used COPY instruction WITH NULL='null'; for csv UDT data  {a:2, b:(a), c:'null'} however generates error message code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message : line 1:214 no viable alternative at input ',' (..a:2, 3:(a), [,]..). and csv data field generated {a:2, b:'null', c:'null'} , COPY instruction generates error message code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message : line 1:214 extraneous input 'c:'null' expecting '}' (....a:2, b:'null', c:'null' [}]..). Have persisted with making the UDT the primary key however has 'null' values within UDT created a primary key violation?

Comment: @John I expanded my answer to include an example of null columns and how they appear in CSV files. I believe that UDT as primary key can have some columns null, but not all of them.

Comment: Thank you, Brian. I have been encountering persistent syntax error messages when inserting data for an alpha numeric UDT which is derived from two other UDTs. Creating UDT one data field “{column 1: column2 <int>, column3 <int>}” and UDT two data field “{column 4: column5 <(text)>, column6 <(text)>}” have worked fine.
Syntax problem occurs with alpha numeric UDT data field “{{column 1: column2 <int>, column3 <int>}, {column 4: column5 <text>, column6 <text>}}"  i.e. when I combine letters in brackets i.e. ‘(a)’ with ‘(b)’ e.g. ‘(a)(b)’ and ‘(a)’’(b)’. Combining letters ‘a’ and ‘b’ works fine.

Comment: @John I don't quite follow your example there, but have you tried the approach of creating data in cqlsh, then exporting to csv, then importing it back? That usually helps clarify the csv syntax. It's possible there are limits to how much nesting of UDTs can be handled by the csv format.